# Supersede the default Apache config on a different config file

Tags: ubuntu, php, .htaccess, apache-2.4, configuration

I'm using Ubuntu with Apache 2.4. The config file for Apache is found at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` at the end of this config file it's written

```
# Current File: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf
```

Where my other config file is found `override.conf`

```
# Current File: /etc/apache2/conf-available/override.conf
<Directory /var/www/>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

However the problem is when I restart Apache my the `AllowOverride All` directive from `override.conf` isn't respected. I can confirm it when I view my `phpinfo()` on the web. But when I change this on the `apache2.conf` file

```
# Current File: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

That is only when `AllowOverride All` take effect.

I did restart Apache and did `a2enconf override` but still it looks like all my external config files are being superseded by the default config file `apache2.conf`

Comment: Retagged as apache-2.4.  This must be 2.4, because of the IncludeOptional directive.  That's also current as of Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Thanks do you have any idea why the default `apache2.conf` is superseding any `IncludeOptional` (included) configurations?

Comment: See if you can view the output of `http://hostname/server-status` or `apache2ctl fullstatus`, and look to be sure that your override.conf is being read.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman been trying that but it gives me a Not Found error. Is there another way to know?

Comment: That's the supported way.  Try enabling mod_status and restarting.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman I got it running here's the [server-status](https://gist.github.com/a0ec535e517c48b285ad.git) How do I identify if the config is loaded from there?